# Don't trim tab(\t) from start/end of a String in JAVA

Tags: java, string, trim

I have an input stream which has fields separated by tab(\t)
which looks like this

```
String str = "  acc123\tdpId123\t2011-01-01\t2022-01-01\thello@xyz.com\tIN\t1233\tSOMETHING      ";
```

which works fine when I do `str = str.trim();` and

```
strArray = str.split("\t", -1); 
strArray=["acc123","dpId123","2011-01-01","2022-01-01","hello@xyz.com","IN","1233","SOMETHING"] will give size as 8
```

But last field in the input record is not mandatory and can be skipped.

So the input can look like this too.

```
 String str1 = "acc123\tdpId123\t2011-01-01\t2022-01-01\thello@xyz.com\tIN\t1233\t";
```

but in this case last field should be empty but when I use this string after trim and split my size is 7

```
str1 = str1.trim();      
strArray = str1.split("\t", -1); 
      strArray=["acc123","dpId123","2011-01-01","2022-01-01","hello@xyz.com","IN","1233"]will give size as 7
```

But I want

```
strArray=["acc123","dpId123","2011-01-01","2022-01-01","hello@xyz.com","IN","1233",""]
```

How can I avoid this situation?

Comment: For the two sample strings you gave us, what are the actual outputs you want to see, and what are the rules deciding what you want to see?

Comment: Why are you trimming a String with no leading or trailing whitespace? Just don't trim it!

Comment: Updated description

Comment: @AjahnCharles I might get white spaces at start and end of string, this is expected. I have changed the first example also.

Comment: I have got one solution but I am not sure about it. If before trimming the String, I just replace \t with some other delimiter. and then use trim(). But this solution actually may not work in some cases, when we can get same delimiter in the input field

Comment: why do you use trim?

Comment: @Faris To trim down spaces at start and end otherwise my first and last field will have spaces like in the example above "SOMETHING      " as my last input field.

Comment: you can split first and then trim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There you go:

```
String str1 = "   acc123\tdpId 123\t201 1-01-01\t2022-01-01\thello@xyz.com\tIN\t1233\t";
str1 = str1.replaceAll("^[ ]+", ""); // removing leading spaces
str1 = str1.replaceAll("[ ]+$", ""); // removing trailing spaces
String[] split = str1.split("\t", -1);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
System.out.println(split.length);
```

[String#trim](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) method also removes `\t`. To handle that I have removed only the leading and trailing spaces using regex.

**Output:**

```
[acc123, dpId 123, 201 1-01-01, 2022-01-01, hello@xyz.com, IN, 1233, ]
8
```

Comment: It will replace all the whitespaces in my fields as well.

Comment: @Bhavesh check the output. It didn't replace the spaces inside the fields.

Comment: Yeah. This regex only matches leading and trailing spaces (no other whitespaces).

Comment: @Bhavesh if it solved your problem, consider accepting this answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use split like so :

```
String[] split = str.split("\t", -1); // note the -1
```

To avoid spaces you can use

```
 Arrays.stream(split).map(String::trim).toArray(String[]:new);
```

Comment: Could you explain what the -1 does?

Comment: @AjahnCharles "The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array" - from java docs

Comment: @Bhavesh sorry I'm using phone to answer but Faris is correct, and with this solution you should to see that `\t` will be converted to an empty and you will get in str1 8 element in the split result

Comment: @Bhavesh if it doest work then you use another cases that you don't share in you question

Comment: @YCF_L But I am always running trim function before split function. As this code is not specific to \t. I am creating a library where delimiter can be variable input.

Comment: It doesnt related to `\t` it will work with any delimiter for example instead of `\t` you use `#` you will get the correct result

Comment: @Bhavesh if you want to avoid spaces then trim then split

Comment: @YCF_L you mean split and then trim.

Comment: @Bhavesh No I meant what I said

Comment: @YCF_L But If you consider my second input string str1, trim() will remove \t at the end considering it as whitespace.

Comment: @Bhavesh, if you are creating a library with variable delimiter char, you won't have the liberty of trimming your inputs like that. Since the delimiter may be declared as a space char as well. I again advise you read the CSV format carefully - it is built to handle these cases, the only restriction it has is that `delimiter`, `escape` and `row-delimiter` must be three different chars.

Comment: @Bhavesh check my edit the code is not tested as I use phone but the idea is there

Comment: @YCF_L This looks like split and then trimming all fields. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @YCF_L that would replace the leading and trailing spaces in each value. Suppose `"\t  abc 1 \t"` would become: `"abc 1"` (leading and trailing spaces removed).

Comment: @Bhavesh exactly it will solit then trim each element not just the first and the last

Comment: @Mushif Ali Nawaz this is correct the question is missing some cases and this make it hard to guess what the OP want exactly

Answer (score 1):

you can use limit parameter to solve this `str.split("\t",-1)` .

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array.

read more about split limit in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)).

**Example:**

```
public class GFG { 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        String str = "a\tb\tc\t"; 
        String[] arrOfStr = str.split("\t",-1); 

        for (String a : arrOfStr) 
            System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(arrOfStr.length);
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The conceptually correct way to do this in your case is to *split first*, only then trim first and last elements:

```
String[] array = str.split("\t");
array[0] = array[0].trim();
int last = array.length -1;
if (last > 0) {
    array[last] = array[last].trim();
}
```

Also, if you know upfront how many fields there is supposed to be, then you should also use that knowledge, otherwise you can get an invalid number of fields still:

```
int fieldsCount = getExpectedFieldsCount();
String[] array = str.split("\t", fieldsCount);
```

---

Lastly, I advise you to **not** use whitespace as the data separator. Use something else. For example, see [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) format, it's a lot better for these things.

Comment: You are right about using CSV format. But for my library code I do want to support tab \t as well. Use case can be if input field contain address of a user. And Address field can have comma.

Comment: @Bhavesh, it's already handled in the format. If field data contains separator char, then that cell's data is wrapped in double quotes. In your case, any and all field can also contain a tab, so you've got the same problem, just (maybe) not as apparent.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (the result array is in the variable resultArray):

```
    String str1 = "acc123\tdpId123\t2011-01-01\t2022-01-01\thello@xyz.com\tIN\t1233\t";
    String[] strArray = str1.split("\t");
    String regex = ".*\\t$";
    String[] resultArray;
    if (str1.matches(regex)) {
        resultArray = new String[strArray.length + 1];
        resultArray[strArray.length] = "";
    } else {
        resultArray = new String[strArray.length];
    }
    for (int i= 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
        resultArray[i] = strArray[i];
    }

    System.out.println(resultArray.length);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resultArray));
```